# Spring Batch CommandLineRunner with multiple bean config files

Tags: spring, batch-processing, spring-batch

I'm writing a Spring Batch application and have split the Spring Beans Configuration into multiple files;

- batch/launchContext.xml (JobLauncher/JobRepository etc)
- batch/common.xml (common beans used in all jobs)
- dataSource.xml (the data source)
- batch/jobs/myJob.xml (individual files for jobs)

The reason for this is because I wish the data source to be changed between dev/test/production setup and also to save re-writing the same bean definitions over-and-over again.

The problem lies when I wish to launch a Spring Batch application.  When reading the instructions here http://static.springsource.org/spring-batch/reference/html/configureJob.html#runningJobsFromCommandLine it assumes one Spring configuration file per job, but that's not how I wish to do it.

How may I run a Spring Batch job, from the command line, which uses multiple bean configuration files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could always just import contexts:

So in `batch/jobs/myJob.xml`:

```
<import resource="batch/launchContext.xml" />
<import resource="batch/common.xml" />
<import resource="dataSource.xml" />
```

See also in [Spring Docs](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/spring-framework-reference.html#beans-factory-xml-import)

EDIT:

You can use a properties placeholder to externalise your data source property definitions:

In your `dataSource.xml`:

```
<bean id="dataSource" destroy-method="close"
    class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
  <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}"/>
  <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}"/>
  <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}"/>
  <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}"/>
</bean>

<context:property-placeholder 
   location="classpath:com/foo/jdbc.properties" 
   systemPropertiesMode="2" />  <!-- 2 means override -->
```

Your `jdbc.properties` would contain the default values:

```
jdbc.driverClassName=org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver
jdbc.url=jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://production:9002
jdbc.username=sa
jdbc.password=root
```

but because using the "override" system properties mode, these can be specified at runtime:

```
java -Djdbc.url=jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://dev:9002 ...
```

See also [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/xsd-config.html#xsd-config-body-schemas-context-pphc)

Comment: Yes that would work.  The only thing that concerns me is that I cannot configure the data source at run time.  This is especially important for configuring different dev/test/production setups.

Comment: yes this works when happy to place the properties in the file... but not when the data source could in fact be a JNDI based one or a local "test" one.  In the former the definition looks somewhat different and therefore cannot be parameterized.  That said I've ticked your answer as I could use a System variable to pick up the appropriate dataSource.xml file.